# Find $\omega_2:\Bbb{R}^2→\Bbb{R}$ s.t $\exists$ a $C^\infty$ function $f:\Bbb{R}^2→\Bbb{R}$ for which $df=e^{xy}dx+\omega_2 dy$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-analysis

I am not sure where to begin on this problem, other than that this problem resembles the structure $df = g\,dx + f\,dy$. This exercise is written in the path independence section of the book, but I am unsure where path independence will play a role here

Comment: Are you sure you've written the problem correctly?  Integrating with respect to $x$ gives us that $f(x,y) = \frac{e^{x y}}{y}+g(y)$ where $g(y)$ is some function depending only on $y$. Such an $f$ isn't going to be defined on the $x-$axis.

Comment: I'm sure its correct. It's exercise 9.3.2 in Lebl real analysis II. https://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal2.pdf